# Expected behaviour of Java interfaces

Tags: java, interface

I'm very surprise by a non expected behaviour of a class I'm building (kind of Composite pattern).

Here's the point and the classes involved :

- `IGroupable` is an interface with 2 methods

  public interface IGroupable {

  ```
  BigDecimal getTotal();
  Boolean isManuallySettlable();
  ```

  }
- `Event` class implements `IGroupable`

  @Entity
  @Table(name="V_ALL_BUSINESS_EVENTS")
  public class EventView implements IGroupable, Serializable {

  ```
  @Id
  @Column(name="UNIQUE_ID")
  private long eventId;
  ...

  @Override
  public BigDecimal getTotal() {
      return this.eventGrossAmount;
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean isManuallySettlable() {
      return (this.eventIsManuallySettlable == null || this.eventIsManuallySettlable == false) ? false : true; 
  }
  ```
- `AbstractGroup` abstract class implements `IGroupable` :

  public abstract class AbstractGroup implements IGroupable, Serializable {

  ```
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected int nbRows;
  protected transient List<IGroupable> groups;
  ...
  ```
- `CurrencyGroup`, `BuyerPlatformGroup` and `CounterpartExecDateGroup` all extend `AbstractGroup`, so each has a `List<IGroupable> groups` property

  public class CurrencyGroup extends AbstractGroup {

  ```
  protected String currency;

  // --------------------------------------------------------

  public CurrencyGroup(String currency) {
      this.currency = currency;
      super.groups = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  ...

  @Override
  public BigDecimal getTotal() {
      BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
      total = this.groups.stream()
          .map(groupable -> groupable.getTotal())
          .reduce(total, BigDecimal::add);
      return total;
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean isManuallySettlable() {
      boolean isSettlable = true;
      for(IGroupable g : groups) {
          if(!g.isManuallySettlable()) {
              isSettlable = false;
          }
      }
      return isSettlable;
  }
  ```

  public class BuyerPlatformGroup extends AbstractGroup {

  ```
  protected String buyerName;
  protected String buyerRTS;
  protected String platform;

  // --------------------------------------------------------

  public BuyerPlatformGroup(String buyerName, String buyerRTS, String platform) {
      this.buyerName = buyerName;
      this.buyerRTS = buyerRTS;
      this.platform = platform;
      super.groups = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public BigDecimal getTotal() {
      BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
      total = this.groups.stream()
          .map(groupable -> groupable.getTotal())
          .reduce(total, BigDecimal::add);
      return total;
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean isManuallySettlable() {
      boolean isSettlable = true;
      for(IGroupable g : groups) {
          if(!g.isManuallySettlable()) {
              isSettlable = false;
          }
      }
      return isSettlable;
  }
  ```

  }

  public class CounterpartExecDateGroup extends AbstractGroup {

  ```
  protected String counterpart;
  protected Date execDate;
  protected BigDecimal amount;
  protected String step;
  protected String operationType;

  // --------------------------------------------------------

  public CounterpartExecDateGroup() {
      super.groups = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  ...

  @Override
  public BigDecimal getTotal() {
      BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
      total = groups.stream()
          .map(groupable -> groupable.getTotal())
          .reduce(total, BigDecimal::add);
      return total;
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean isManuallySettlable() {
      boolean isSettlable = true;
      for(IGroupable g : groups) {
          if(!g.isManuallySettlable()) {
              isSettlable = false;
          }
      }
      return isSettlable;
  }
  ```

  }

-> they all inherit from 'AbstractGroup' and also all are 'IGroupable' objects

```
@Test
    public void allIGroupableTest() {

        List<EventView> events = eventDao.findAll();
        EventView event = (EventView) events.get(0);

        CurrencyGroup ccyGrp = new CurrencyGroup("EUR");
        BuyerPlatformGroup buyerGrp = new BuyerPlatformGroup(event.getEventBuyerName(), event.getEventRTSCode(), event.getEventPlatform());
        CounterpartExecDateGroup counterpartGrp = new CounterpartExecDateGroup();

        ccyGrp.addGroup(buyerGrp); // OK
        buyerGrp.addGroup(counterpartGrp); // OK
        counterpartGrp.setGroups(events); **// ERROR**
```

But I've got an error, telling me : The method `setGroups(List<IGroupable>)` in the type `AbstractGroup` is not applicable for the arguments `(List<EventView>)`.

Why does it behave this way ?
As the `Event` class implements `IGroupable` interface, a list of `IGroupable` objects should be able to accept a list of `Events`, isn't it ?

Comment: please show us your code instead of describing it. It will be much easier to understand the problem this way.

Comment: Also, try to format your question such that class names and inline code are in backticks, and don't use plain apostrophes as these cause confusion. And of course, use the `{}` button for any block of code.

Comment: `EventView` is not `Event`, is it?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.